# In jest, how do I mock an instance of mongodb.Db for a unit test?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I'm using jest and mongoose 5.11.11.  I have the following function I want to unit test ...

```
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
...
export async function createCollectionIfNotExists(
  db: Db,
  collectionName: string,
): Promise<void> {
  if (!(await collectionExists(db, collectionName))) {
    await db.createCollection(collectionName);
  }
}
```

How do I create a mock object of type "mongodb.Db"?  I see a way to spy on existing prototype methods using

```
jest.spyOn(Db.prototype, 'createCollection').mockImplementation( ...
```

but I first have to construct a Db instance and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mocked `db` object and pass it to `createCollectionIfNotExists` function. Use type assertions to specify the mocked `db` object type to `Db`.

Besides, I suggest you move the `collectionExists` function to a separate file (use `jest.mock('./collectionExists')` method to mock). Or use dependency injection like `db` (create mocked version like this `const collectionExists = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(false)`), so that we can mock it easily.

```
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
import { createCollectionIfNotExists } from './';

describe('67913785', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mDb = ({ createCollection: jest.fn() } as unknown) as Db;
    await createCollectionIfNotExists(mDb, 'posts');
    expect(mDb.createCollection).toBeCalledWith('posts');
  });
});
```